# How to use an external sd card and recharge the battery at the same time

Tags: battery, charging, usb-connection-mode, samsung-nexus-10

I'm an happy owner of the tablet nexus 10. It is very good. Some time ago I've bought the leef connector because I want to use an external sd card :

[image]

as you can see from the picture,there is a problem. When I keep attached the leef connector I can't recharge the battery. Do you know if there is some way to do both things at the same time ? I want to use the external sd card but when the battery is going to be very low I want to attach the tablet to one USB port or to the wall outlet. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have an OTG adapotor that looks like this
[image]

It accepts SD, microSD and USB memory sticks while charging. It's a bit bulkier than what you've got, but it may be worth trying. This one was made for the Galaxy S2, and it works well with the Galaxy S3 and the Galaxy S5 as well (those are the ones I've tried it with, and it probably works with most Samsung devices). There should be similar devices for your tablet or for generic Nexus devices as well.

Comment: can you suggest to me a more cute OTG adapter that works for my tablet ? it is very bulky ! thanks.

Comment: @Marietto "Very bulky" is an exaggeration. It's only about 3x1x0.5 cm. I only meant to show you that solutions exist, and the reason I included an image of this specific adaptor, is that it's what I've got at hand. Finding one that is more fit for your needs, is up to you. [Google](http://www.google.com) and [Pricerunner](http://www.pricerunner.com) are your friends.